# ASP.NET Core API not accepting null value for a nullable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a GET request API endpoint that receives a request View Model with a Nullable property like this:

```
public class ModelRequestVM : BaseRequestVM
    {
        #region Properties and Data Members
        public uint ModelId { get; set; }
        public uint? MakeId { get; set; }
        public string MakeName { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public uint? ExternalModelId { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

but when I make a get request for `MakeId` with a `null` value, The API is not accepting `null` value for this nullable type.

this is my get request: `https://localhost:44311/api/model/getlist?MakeId=null`

I get the following error:

`The value 'null' is not valid for MakeId.`

Comment: Won't it receive null if you just omit it completely?

Comment: @AFriend I actually want it to receive some value based upon which I can get all the models.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MakeId is a `Nullable<uint>` but `MakeId=null` in the query string `null` is just a string value which can not be parsed as uint. just remove it from your request to make it null:

```
https://localhost:44311/api/model/getlist
```

You can do something like this to include makeid if it's not null:

```
string url = $"https://localhost:44311/api/model/getlist(makeid == null?"":"?makeid=" + makeid)";
```

Comment: I actually want it to receive some value based upon which I can get all the models. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: well to send null value for makeid you have to omit it from query string, let me edit my answer to show how to do it.

Comment: I understand that. the question is I'm using it in a generic endpoint where at least one value will be passed to it. that's the use case

Comment: lets say on the other hand there is a code like `Request.QueryString["makeid"]` that is getting what you pass as makeid, what will be it's value you you don't have a querystring parameter named `makeid`? `null` that's the way to do it, there is nothing else that you can pass for null value unless api maps a specific string to null

Comment: I can't pass any value other than an actual `unit` value to the request not even empty `""` not even just `MakeId=` as the request will fail even before hitting the method and that is going to cause me trouble in my application logic

Comment: `MakeId=` means makeid = empty string, if you completely omit it, it will be null. see this: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/vgdzps](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vgdzps)

Comment: I understand, seems like that is the only solution and that is going be a trouble for us. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually receiving the string "null" and can not convert it to `uint`.

The value would be null if you omit it.

Comment: I actually want it to receive some value based upon which I can get all the models. Is there a way to do this?